# Reading output of a function as an input in another function

Tags: matlab

I have wrote a program which it has two functions. The first one's output is a matrix like:
`Z = [1 2 3]`
The second function should use the output of the previous one. But it can't read the matrix `Z`.
Can you help please?

My first function is something like this:

```
function ff = firststep(z)

sigme1=z(5)* exp(-z(1)*10^12*(t-z(2)*10^-6).^2).*cos(2*pi*z(3)*10^6*(t-z(2)*10^-6)+z(4));

ff =sum((y-sigme).^2)/NN;
end
```

it is used in an optimization toolbox which after optimizing it the output is a matrix `z` which I have in my workspace.
My second function is like this:

```
function ff = secstep(zz)
sigme1=zz(1)* exp(-z(1)*10^12*(t-zz(2)*10^-6).^2).*cos(2*pi*z(3)*10^6*(t-zz(2)*10^-6)+z(4));

end
```

I have also been attempting to optimize this function, but this time matlab can't call (what I meant by reading in my first post) matrix z.
The error is this:

```
Undefined function 'z' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Comment: Please post the code (or shortened versions) of your two functions as well as the code where you call these functions. What do you mean it can't read the matrix `Z`?

Comment: either you need to pass the variable to your second function or make it global.

Comment: Do you need to use both `zz` and the original `z` in `secstep`?? If so then rather declare `function ff = secstep(zz, z)`. Otherwise change  all your `z`s to `zz`s

Comment: I found my answer. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimization algorithm that I was using was GA(Genetic Algorithm). I wrote this function in order to get what I wanted:

```
function [zz,fvalzz] = secstep(z,NVARS)
 [zz,fvalzz]=ga(@secfun,NVARS);

function ff = secfun(zz)
 y=.5*exp(-35*10^12*(t-2e-6).^2).*cos(2*pi*5e6*(t-2e-6)+0);

sigme2=zz(1)* exp(-z(1)*10^12*(t-zz(2)*10^-6).^2).*cos(2*pi*z(3)*10^6*(t-zz(2)*10^-6)+z(4)); %z vector has been calculated from another function.
NN=length(y);   
ff =sum((y-sigme2).^2)/NN;
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking your code I should say that, you need to **pass** the variables to your function or make the variables **global**. check out the following link:

[How declare a global variable in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html)

example:

```
function tic
%    TIC Start a stopwatch timer.
%        TIC; any stuff; TOC
%    prints the time required.
%    See also: TOC, CLOCK.
global TICTOC
TICTOC = clock;

function t = toc
%    TOC Read the stopwatch timer.
%    TOC prints the elapsed time since TIC was used.
%    t = TOC; saves elapsed time in t, does not print.
%    See also: TIC, ETIME.
global TICTOC
if nargout < 1
    elapsed_time = etime(clock, TICTOC)
else
    t = etime(clock, TICTOC);
end
```

I suggest you declare the z as a global variable in each function and in the main file simply:

```
global z
```

Comment: i post some of my codes

Comment: I found my answer. Thanks so much.